# JavaMail Folder search() method returns multiple messages for a unique MessageID

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap

JavaMail Folder.search() returns multiple IMAP messages even if a MessageIDTerm is passed to the method. It seems to happen when the messages are subsequent forwards of an orginal message. JavaMail version is 1.4.4. The mail server is MS Exchange 2013. Users send emails with MS Outlook.
Here is the code:

```
            MessageIDTerm messageIDTerm = new MessageIDTerm(uniqueMessageID);
            Message[] messages = folder.search(messageIDTerm);
```

If the uniqueMessageID is a message ID of an email the has been forwarded, the messages array will contain the message with uniqueMessageID and all the subsequent forwarded messages. 
Is this behaviour correct? Is there any way to get only the message with the messagedID passed to the search method?

Comment: The message-ID isn't necessarily unique. It's sender-specifed data, and some senders are buggy.

Comment: I'm sure the message id is unique. I have a test case with four messages and they have distinct message ids:                                                          <D3EF01F72AAC374C9BF08A334D00B40C42D3E078@xxx.xx> <D3EF01F72AAC374C9BF08A334D00B40C42D3E0AC@xxx.xx> <D3EF01F72AAC374C9BF08A334D00B40C42D3E0D1@xxx.xx> <D3EF01F72AAC374C9BF08A334D00B40C42D3E0EE@xxx.xx> The first id is the id of the original message, the other are the ids of three forwards of the original message made by the same user, If you search for the first MessageID, you get all the four messages.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's a bug in Exchange.  Turn on [JavaMail Session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and it should provide enough information for you to report the bug to Microsoft.

Are the forwarded messages being sent as attachments to a new message?  If so, Exchange may be searching for the header in the attachments as well as the main message, which would be wrong.

BTW, you might want to upgrade to the [current 1.5.3 version of JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Comment: RFC 3501 page 51 doesn't actually say that the field has to be in the top-level header... sloppy writing perhaps.

Comment: @Bill: The forwarded messages are sent as separate messages, not as attachments.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear in context that the messages it's talking about are the messages that are directly referenced in the IMAP protocol, not the parts of messages that might themselves be other messages.

Comment: There are common ways to forward a message, described in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#forward).  A third approach is to "resend" the message so that it appears to come from the original sender, not from the person resending the message.  According to RFC 2822, in this case the Message-ID from the original message should be preserved.  Additional "Resent" header fields are prepended to the message.  If that were what's happening, it would not be an error to find those messages.  But since you say the Message-IDs are different, that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

To get only the Messages try this

```
public void loadFolder() {
    if (store != null && store.isConnected()) {
       try {
            final Folder inbox = store.getFolder("foldername");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            final FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.USER), false);
            final Message[] messages = inbox.search(ft);

        for (Message message : messages) {
            try {
                if (message.getContentType().contains("text")) {
                    final String text = (String) message.getContent();
                    System.out.println(text);
                 }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.error("", e);
            }
            }
        }
```

With the Flag you can specify your search